# Objectify return List & Cursor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am trying to use a cursor with Objectify and Google App Engine to return a subset of data and a cursor so that I can retrieve more data when the user is ready.  I found an example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/IRGe-GWcSWo) that looks exactly like what I need but I don't know how to return the final list plus the cursor.  Here is the code I have:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listIconThemeCursor") //https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Cursors
public CollectionResponse<IconTheme> listIconThemeCursor(@Named("cursor") String cursorStr) {
    Query<IconTheme> query = ofy().load().type(IconTheme.class).limit(10);
    if (cursorStr != null ) {
        query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorStr));
    }
    List<IconTheme> result = new ArrayList<IconTheme>();
    int count = 0;
    QueryResultIterator<IconTheme> iterator = query.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        IconTheme theme = iterator.next();
        result.add(theme);
        count++;
    }
    Cursor cursor = iterator.getCursor();
    String encodeCursor = cursor.toWebSafeString();
    return serial(tClass, result, encodeCursor);
}
```

Note that this was modified from a previous endpoint in which I returned the CollectionResponse of ALL the data.  My dataset is large enough that this is no longer practical.  Basically, I don't know what was in the user's function of 'serial(tClass, result, encodeCursor) that let it get returned to the user.

There is another example [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Cursors) but it doesn't appear to answer my question either.

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite understand what you are asking, but I see one immediate bug in your code:

```
query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorStr));
```

...should be:

```
query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorStr));
```

Objectify command objects are immutable, functional objects.

Comment: Nice catch on that (I'm sure it would have killed me later).  Basically though, I don't know what 'return serial(tClass, result, encodeCursor) is.  I only know how to return a CollectionResponse, not how to return the ArrayList + Cursor.

Comment: This is a question for someone familiar with Google Endpoints. I suggest you tag the question with the google endpoints tag to get the right eyes on it.

Comment: Thank you, that saved my life!

Answer (score 5):

After a long slog, I figured out that CollectionResponse has the cursor in it :(

Here is the complete code I used incorporating the comment from stickfigure above:

```
   @ApiMethod(name = "listIconThemeCursor", path="get_cursor") 
    public CollectionResponse<IconTheme> listIconThemeCursor(@Named("cursor") String cursorStr) {
        Query<IconTheme> query = ofy().load().type(IconTheme.class)
                .filter("errors <", 10)
                .limit(10);
        if (cursorStr != null ) {
            query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorStr));
        }
        List<IconTheme> result = new ArrayList<IconTheme>();
        QueryResultIterator<IconTheme> iterator = query.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            IconTheme theme = iterator.next();
            result.add(theme);
        }
        Cursor cursor = iterator.getCursor();
        CollectionResponse<IconTheme> response = CollectionResponse.<IconTheme> builder()
                .setItems(result)
                .setNextPageToken(cursor.toWebSafeString())
                .build();

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Really appreciate this. Can't find CollectionResponse Javadocs, so this was hugely helpful.

Comment: Should cursorStr also be `@Nullable`?

Comment: I guess it could @willlma but it will run just fine without it.